# Why declaring integer non-type template parameters const?

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking at a library and I see template parameter declarations as [such](https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl/blob/796752172c8498b79932974fcdfc80c6b8d7bcc9/include/etl/scaled_rounding.h#L67):

```cpp
template <const size_t SCALING, typename T>
T round_ceiling_unscaled(T value) { /* ... */ }
```

I am wondering, does it make any difference if the first template parameter is declared as

- `const size_t SCALING` or
- `size_t SCALING`

I would assume that integers as template parameters would always be `const` or `constexpr`? Am I missing something?

Comment: non-type template parameters are naturally compile time constants, so I think it's just someone taking const correctness to the max.

Comment: Probably force of habbit, like constant SHOUTING.

Comment: Looks like that has changed a little.  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter): *When the name of a non-type template parameter is used in an expression within the body of the class template, it is an unmodifiable prvalue unless its type was an lvalue reference type, or unless its type is a class type (since C++20).*

Comment: @NathanOliver The note in the [draft N4861](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) (C++20) in §14.1 [temp.param] p8 says *if it is of
class type `T`, it is an lvalue and has type `const T`*. So I guess for non-reference types the result is the same; you get a `const T` in any case?

Comment: @user5534993 I believe so.